# Simulation of large quantum circuits or available dataset

Tags: simulation

I need to obtain the expectation value of an observable (I do not care which one) of simulated large quantum circuits, like 30 or more qubits. The quantum circuit can be of any type, but it is important that it isn't one of those easy to simulate (Clifford, separable circuits, etc.).

Is there any available dataset?

Or what's the best way to simulate this kind of quantum circuit (even if I need days, GPUs, etc.)?

Comment: Is it about the number of qubits or the number of features in the dataset?
If it is the number features, you may think about using Amplitude Encoding to use fewer number of qubits.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate large quantum circuits (30+ qubits), you need huge memory ressources, to achieve this, current simulators use HPC systems.

One of the most efficient quantum simulators is the [Atos QLM](https://atos.net/en/solutions/quantum-learning-machine), showing best simulation time, and having powerful software libraries for quantum computing development.